# Creating a route works in one branch, but not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a new "public_speaking" route by adding an entry in pages_controller.rb:

```
def public_speaking
end
```

I also created a barebones view file for "public_speaking.html.erb" and added a route in routes.rb as follows:

```
get 'home/public_speaking'
```

**-or-**

```
get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'
```

I have tried both versions of the route and it worked in one of my branches, but I tried copying and pasting the code into another branch and the same steps don't yield any entry for a "public_speaking" route when I run "rails routes" in my console.

What on earth could cause a new route to be created in one branch but not another? What else should I try?

The full routes.rb file looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "pages#home"

  get 'home/public_speaking'

  get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
  resources :users do 
      resource :profile
  end 

  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

  resources :contacts, only: [:create]

  get 'contact-us', to: 'contacts#new', as: 'new_contact'

  get 'home/public_speaking'

  get 'public_speaking', to: 'pages#public_speaking'

end
```

The full pages controller looks like:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  # GET request for / which is our home page
      def home 
        @basic_plan = Plan.find(1)
        @pro_plan = Plan.find(2)
      end 

      def about
      end 

      def offerings
      end 

      def public_speaking
      end
end
```

---

Editing to add the results of "rails routes" for the working branch:

```
rails routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
              pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)                  pages#home
             pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)                 pages#about
         pages_offerings GET    /pages/offerings(.:format)             pages#offerings
   pages_public_speaking GET    /pages/public_speaking(.:format)       pages#public_speaking
                    root GET    /                                      pages#home
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#destroy
            user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                         GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                       pages#about
                contacts POST   /contacts(.:format)                    contacts#create
             new_contact GET    /contact-us(.:format)                  contacts#new
               offerings GET    /offerings(.:format)                   pages#offerings
ubuntu@ip-172-31-91-225:~/environment/saasapp$
```

---

And the branch where it doesn't work:

```
 rails routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                                      pages#home
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#destroy
            user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                         GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
                   about GET    /about(.:format)                       pages#about
                contacts POST   /contacts(.:format)                    contacts#create
             new_contact GET    /contact-us(.:format)                  contacts#new
               offerings GET    /offerings(.:format)                   pages#offerings
```

Comment: I don't think this can have anything to do with branches, the only thing I can imagine is that somehow the changes to the routes file have not taken effect. Did you restart the server after changing the `routes.rb`?

Comment: How do you restart the server? Literally refresh the page or is there some command or option?